# Как сделать один метод fill, show для 2 разных конструктора?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    int size = 0;
    int n, m;
    int **p=nullptr;
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(int i) :size(i)
    {
        p = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] = new int[size];

    }

    Matrix(int i, int j) :n(i), m(j)
    {
        p = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] = new int[m];
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            delete[] p[i];
        delete[] p;
    }

    void fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                p[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    void show()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                cout << p[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    Matrix a(5);
    a.fill();
    a.show();

    Matrix b(5, 3);
    b.fill();
    b.show();

    return 0;
}
```

И ещё один вопрос. В моём примере 2 конструктора, значит нужно создавать 2 конструктора копирования?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вашу задачу - вам не два конструктора, а два класса делать надо, а сейчас вы "хотите странного"

Comment: А про метод fill и show, как сделать один метод для 2 конструктора?

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в свой вопрос? У класса есть методы, в том числе конструкторы, которые тоже являются методами. Сделать метод для метода это "хотеть странного". Опишите точнее, чего хотите добиться.

Comment: Как сделать один метод fill, show для 2 разных конструктора? Что бы с помощью одного метода можно было вызвать конструктор с один параметром и с двумя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как сделать один метод fill, show

```
class Matrix{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    int **p = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(int i) : Matrix(i,i)
    {
    }

    Matrix(int i, int j) :n(i), m(j)
    {
        p = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            p[i] = new int[m];
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            delete[] p[i];
        delete[] p;
    }

    void fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                p[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    void show()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            {
                cout << p[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << std::endl;
        }
        cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

> В моём примере 2 конструктора, значит нужно создавать 2 конструктора копирования?

Нет